# Access static method from other package

Tags: java, swing, package, jbutton

first of all, some Information about the project:
Structure:

- `src/public` class `Board`
- `src/Pieces/public` `abstract class Piece extends JButton`
- `src/Pieces/public` `class One extends Piece`

In class `Board` is a method

```
public static void selectPiece(Piece piece) {
    this.selectedPiece = piece
}
```

I want to call when one of the pieces is clicked.

How can I do this?

Comment: this is a static method. It is public, that means that it doesn't matter whether the class that wants to call it is within the same package or not. Add an import statement and ClassName.methodName(parameters); should do. As for on the click: look into ActionListeners

Comment: First: `public static` setter seems to be a bad design. Second: `Board.selectPiece(...)`

Comment: Thats kind of my problem, I dont know how to import the 'Main' class from a 'lower' package. And helpfully, IntelliSense doesnt help here either

Comment: There is no reason to dable with UI's and Listeners before knowing the basics. being able to import classes: quite basic.

Comment: Assuming `Board.java` starts with `package public;` then just `import public.Board;`, then you can refer to it as `Board` and call the method as `Board.selectPiece(...)` as Stefan Warminski suggested.

Comment: _I dont know how to import the 'Main' class from a 'lower' package_ sounds like it's time to work through a tutorial on java language basics ..

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca aside: wondering since when using keywords as package names is valid java? not up-to java12 (yeah my workspace needs updating ;)

Comment: @kleopatra your workspace needs updating, but yeah, `package public;` is not valid, not even in java 17 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import public.Board;

// to call selectPiece
Board.selectPiece(pieceObj);
```